# $X,Y$ be metric spaces , $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous and closed map , then the boundary of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for every $y \in Y$ ?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, closed-map

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces , $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous and closed map , then is it true that the boundary of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for every $y \in Y$ ?

Comment: Just an idea, but you can consider the Weierstass function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function. My intuition tells me that this function will be a counter example.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Weierstrass’s function is periodic, so it’s not closed.

Comment: Hmm, right, it is not a closed map. That's anoying, I cannot modify the Weierstrass function to overcome this problem and still have unbounded inverse images.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Don’t beat yourself up on this. No one can execute such a modification, because no counterexample exists. :-) See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

The claim is true. A proof is reported by Theorem 1 in [this paper by A. H. Stone](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1956-007-04/S0002-9939-1956-0087078-6/S0002-9939-1956-0087078-6.pdf) (in case you’re wondering, this is *not* the Stone–Weierstrass-theorem guy), which I outline below.

Let $B$ denote the boundary of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ and suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that it is not compact. Then, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $B$ such that none of its subsequences converges to a limit in $B$. Note that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed because $f$ is continuous, so that $f(x_n)=y$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Since $(x_n)_{\in\mathbb N}$ is in the boundary of $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ and $f$ is continuous, there exists a sequence $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ such that the following hold for each $n\in\mathbb N$:

- $(\spadesuit)\quad f(w_n)\neq y$;
- $(\heartsuit)\quad d_X(x_n,w_n)<1/n$;
- $(\clubsuit)\quad d_Y(f(x_n),f(w_n))=d_Y(y,f(w_n))<1/n$.

Let $W\equiv\{w_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, the set consisting of the elements of the sequence $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (after suppressing repeated elements). I claim that $W$ is closed. Indeed, if $W$ is *not* closed, then there exists some $w\in X\setminus W$ and a sequence $(w_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ in $W$ (which, as the notation suggests, can be regarded as a subsequence$^{\star}$ of $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$) such that $w_{n_k}\to w$. But then ($\heartsuit$) implies that $x_{n_k}\to w$ (and $w\in B$ since $B$ is closed), contradicting the assumption that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has no convergent subsequence.

Therefore, $W$ must be closed, and since $f$ is a closed map, $f(W)$ is closed, too. But note that ($\spadesuit$) yields that $y\notin f(W)$, whereas ($\clubsuit$) yields that $y\in\operatorname{cl}f(W)=f(W)$, which is a contradiction.

---

$^{\star}$Remark: Note that it is *not* true that *any* sequence consisting of the members of $W$ is automatically a subsequence of $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, as a subsequence must also obey a certain order structure inherited from the parent sequence. In the argument above, the assumption that $w\notin W$ is needed in a subtle way to establish that $(w_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ can be regarded as a *bona fide* subsequence of $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. I leave it to the Reader to figure out the details.

Comment: Great answer, nice proof as well and actually not so difficult. Too bad the argument isn't longer, you could have used a full deck then.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thank you, I very much appreciate your feedback. ($\diamondsuit$) Now we have a full deck. :-)